# how can i append a $name variable inside a $lang variable?

Tags: php, lang

i have a lang file with lots of pre-made statements

the one i'm working one is used as a template to email users

`$lang['ADD_STORE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TITLE'] = " New store has been added";`

as you guys can probably guessed, the code above is what would be the email title

my question is, how can i put variable in there? say i wanna have the email title as "hello john, new store has been added"

`mail(ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL,$lang['ADD_STORE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TITLE']"From: no-reply@gmail.com");`

i tried adding the 'name' variable before and after the $lang, but it wont work. i tried appending it by name+$lang.... but still wont show up

Comment: The PHP string concatenation operator is `.` not `+`.

Comment: You're not using [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) correctly, and you seem to be missing some basics as well. Try and find a general PHP course/tutorial would be my advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$lang['ADD_STORE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TITLE'] = " New store".$yourVar." has been added";
```

or

```
$lang['ADD_STORE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TITLE'] = " New store has been added".$yourVar;
```

Comment: what if the $yourvar is in a separate document than the  $lang?

Comment: How do these separate documents relate to each other (with eg inclusion, objects)?

Comment: Are you talking about data coming from a form?  You can use $_GET['yourVar'] or $_POST['yourVar'] to get this data depending on how the method of the form is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to accomplish this.

Also. To concatenate strings in PHP, you need to use . instead of +

Ex:

```
mail('email@example.com', sprintf('This is a %s day', 'fine'), sprintf('Hello mr. %s', $name);
```

This will result in an email being sent to email@example.com with the subject "This is a fine day" and body "Hello mr. {some name from the variable"}